# I want a solution to the problems jar?

Tags: android, android-layout

**I want a solution to these problems**

I want to solve these problems

photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3CCj.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHgld.png

There are other pictures in the first to comment

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/dRo5W.png][3]

[http://i.stack.imgur.com/6xi8M.png][4]

Comment: Hurry, guys, **he wants a solution**!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android-support-v4.jar` from your application project. Remove it from your libs folder.

Your other lib already makes use of it, so it will be exported when your lib is.

Comment: There is no file android-support-v4.jar Inside project !!!                                         http://i.stack.imgur.com/dRo5W.png

Comment: The import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment cannot be resolved